# Error 404 in Apache Tomcat using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to run a basic servlet using Eclipse and Tomcat 7.0 but it keeps giving the 404 error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /ServletExample/

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /ServletExample/

description The requested resource (/ServletExample/) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

The different codes are :
Home.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My first JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="HelloServlet">
        Please enter a colour<br>
        <input type="text" name="color" size="20px">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWorld.java

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet
{ 
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    { 
        // reading the user input 
        String color= request.getParameter("color");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        out.println (
            "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" " +
            "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" + 
            "<html> \n" + 
            "<head> \n" + 
            "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n" + 
            "<title> My first jsp </title> \n" + 
            "</head> \n" +
            "<body> \n" + 
            "<font size=\"12px\" color=\"" + color +"\">" + 
            "Hello World" +
            "</font> \n" + 
            "</body> \n" + 
            "</html>" ); 
    } 
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"> 
 <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class> 
 </servlet> 
 <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern> 
 </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

I've followed all the steps specified in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163493/apache-tomcat-404-error)

Yet the error persists.
Please help

Comment: Have you kept the .class files inside classes folder?

Comment: You are calling /ServletExample but your servlet is mapped to /HelloServlet. Btw. an .jsp is not needed for this configuration.

Comment: But the url pattern is **/HelloServlet**, so it's correct submiting /HelloServlet action.

Comment: Please post the URL you're using to access your web application.

Comment: URL - http://localhost:8080/ServletExample/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are accesing **/ServletExample/** and this is your context. Put in your web.xml :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP's not using any JSP at all. Also, as noted in comments, OP's trying to access `http://server/ServletExample` when it should be `http://server/WebApplicationName/HelloServlet/`.

Comment: Thanks! Adding this to the xml did make it work. Could you explain what exactly the problem must have been? And what do I need to take care of in the future?

Comment: @Luiggi, his context is **ServletExample**, when you say `http://server/WebApplicationName/HelloServlet/` it must be `http://server/ServletExample/HelloServlet/`, but he wants to access a page, and then on submit - call the servlet. user2464622, what you did bad is not defining a default page in your web.xml to access the application. Calling `http://server/ServletExample/` and without welcome page the server doesn't know where to redirect the request. Putting a welcome page the server does know what to do. Or, as Luiggi says - always call **server/context/page.jsp** and also will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a URL pattern `/HelloServlet` in your `web.xml`. So you should try to connect `127.0.0.1:8080/HelloServlet`, not `127.0.0.1:8080/ServletExample/`.

Answer (score 0):

Add package name in `web.xml` like this.

```
<servlet-class>package.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
```