# HTTP Status 404 Eclipse Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am getting Error 404 when trying to run my application. 
Tomcat server, start and synchronized. Dynamic module version is 2.5.
Previously I used dynamic module version 3.o but it didn't work. I read in 
one of the posts that better is to use 2.5. so I created new project and 
still get this 4044 error. It is technical error I think.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: stop server, clean [Right click on sever in Servers view and click clean ] . Then do project clean followed by build, redeploy and see . Also just try with a `welcome-file` index.jsp and see if you get the page. Start with minimal.

Comment: also see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163493/apache-tomcat-404-error

Comment: prash - I di all the steps but it didn't work still 404

Comment: so even if you create a dynamic web application, with just a web.xml having welcome-file as index.html , you cannot see the page ?

Comment: I have created just to test now Dynamic web app, with web.xml file and index.html and it worked. It doesn't work for the app I have described problem above.

Comment: Do I miss some library or some jar file?

Comment: in the link you posted someone said: I agree to drvdijk.

" Go to "Servers" window, then select your Tomcat instance. Double.click here you will see the "overview" window. Here you can click on "Open launch configuration" to see your Tomcat arguments ("Arguments" tab).

Look for the system property "-Dwtp.deploy". This directory is where your Tomcat is looking for installed web applications, i think you don't have ROOT.war application here. Isn't it? :-)"   I posted image to that.

Comment: when I type http://localhost:8081/ it display apache tomcat web

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do I need to have main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to create index.jsp WebContent->New->JSP file and it will place it in the right spot. Now I am able to see my index page.

The problem was that I created index.jsp file WEB-INF->New->JSP file. You can see it above in my post.

Here I place the image where you can see image.jsp is place in different spot. You can see small difference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's why I asked you to create a test dynamic project to compare.  I think when you created that new project you placed index.html under WebContent correctly.  So you couldn't figure out with that example.

Also you can place your jsp inside WEB-INF. That's a recommended way too to keep it safe . I mean if the file is inside WebContent a Web user can navigate to the location and access it. But if it is inside WEB-INF the access is controlled by your web.xml. 
So in your former case just give the relative path .ie /WEB-INF/page.jsp